# Running JavaScript specific function from html

Tags: javascript, html

Abit new to html and javascript.

I got a JS script and an html code.

I want to run a specific function in my JS form my html code. how do i do that?

My JS generalRedirect.js:

```
var redirect = {
test1: function () {
    window.alert("sometext");
},
....
```

My HTML:

```
..
<script src="@Url.Content(".../Scripts/generalRedirect.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to run a specific function in my JS form my html code. how do i
>   do that?

You can call your function like this:

```
redirect.test1();
```

and don't forget to put that inside `<script>` tags and also be sure to include the correct file.

Do this:

```
<script src='@Url.Content(".../Scripts/generalRedirect.js")' type="text/javascript></script>
<script>
  redirect.test1();
</script>
```

Comment: tried : <script src="@Url.Content(".../Scripts/generalRedirect.js")" type="text/javascript"> redirect.test1() </script> , not working

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like this:

```
 <script src='@Url.Content(".../Scripts/generalRedirect.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
     redirect.test1();
</script>
```